# Duplicate images - Hover to disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, hover

I am creating a "splash" page and we need it to be filled with a bunch of one certain image. I want it to then remove each individual image as it is hovered. Here is what I have - I have been able to duplicate the image to fill the screen - but now when I hover, they ALL disappear rather than individually. Any thoughts?

Is there also a way to easily rotate / randomly place the clones?

```
<img class='toBeCloned' id="IMAGE_ID" src="image.png" />

<div id='target' class="DIV_CLASS">

<script>
var _clone=$('.toBeCloned');
var _target=$('#target'); //this is target

for(var i=0;i<500;i++){
    _target.append(_clone.clone(true)); //append target, clone every time
};

$(function () {

    $('img').hover(function() {
       $('img').fadeOut("slow");
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('img').hover(function() {
       $(this).fadeOut("slow");
    });
```

You were referencing img on the fadeOut, which will cause all img tags to disappear. using `this` will just make the hovered image disappear.

Comment: Thank you @Shanehoban AWESOME!! Wow That was simple. Is there an easy way to randomly place / position the clones at all?

Comment: I guess you could set the img tags to position absolute in your CSS and attach random margins via jQuery? 

Your welcome dude!